# C++ class for application/program settings?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, configuration, mfc, settings

Using Visual Studio C++ with MFC.  I'm trying to figure out what would be a good way to store application/program settings.  I'm not referring to their persistent storage but to the data structure used in code to hold the settings.

I created a static class called Settings that has several static methods and also nested classes to partition the settings.  For example:

```
class Settings
{
public:
    Settings(void);
    ~Settings(void);

    static void SetConfigFile(const char * path);
    static CString GetConfigFilePath();
    static void Load();
    static void Save();

    class General
    {
    public:
        static CString GetHomePage();
        static void SetHomePage(const char * url);
    private:
        static int homePageUrl_;
    };

private:
    static CString configFilePath_;
};
```

Then I can access my settings throughout my code like:

```
Settings::General::GetHomePage();
```

Now I'm getting into unit testing and I'm starting to realize that static classes are undesirable.  So I want to turn this into an instance based class.  But I'll have to manage the nested class instances which is trivial but still seems a little cumbersome for testing.  The whole intention of the nested classes is simply to group the settings into logical groups.  I'm debating whether a string-based settings class would be better, something like settings->get("General.HomePage") although I think I prefer the strong typing of dedicated accessor methods.

So to get to my question what is a good data structure to hold program configuration/settings that supports straightforward unit testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this if it works for you.  You can ditch the enum and go to const strings or even free-form strings.  The enum doesn't really have to be defined in the class either.  There are lots of ways to do it.

Another class could do something similar with multiple instances using a template to define the enum type if you wanted to implement categories.

Just an idea.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Settings
{
public:

  typedef enum
  {
    HomePageURL,
    EmailAddress,
    CellPhone
  } SettingName;

private:
  typedef map<SettingName, string> SettingCollection;

  SettingCollection theSettings;


public:

  string& operator[](const SettingName& theName)
  {
    return theSettings[theName];
  }

  void Load ()
  {
    theSettings[HomePageURL] = "http://localhost";
  }

  void Save ()
  {
    // Do whatever here
  }

};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  Settings someSettings;

  someSettings.Load ();

  cout << someSettings [Settings::SettingName::HomePageURL] << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is really no point in using `typedef enum bla {} foo` in c++ IMHO. You don't need to write `enum bla varname` when declaring variables. `bla varname` suffices.

Comment: @RedX: In this toy example, I agree.  However, it is often the case that as the code evolves you find that your template params do not fit your needs.  It is much easier to reference SettingCollection::mapped_type or SettingCollection::key_type as types so that if you change the template params in a complicated piece of code, you only change the type in one spot.  This also works well if you have templated types within classes that are themselves templates.  It also shows the purpose of the type as it is used throughout the code as unambiguously being used in the map.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there has to be a conflict between your requirements of: (1) providing type-safe access to configuration variables; and (2) using a `"fully.scoped.name"` syntax to specify the name of a configuration variable. Surely you could have type-safe operations such as:

```
const char * getString(const char * fullyScopedName);
int          getInt(const char * fullyScopedName);
bool         getBool(const char * fullyScopedName);
```

You might find some inspiration by reading Chapters 2 and 3 of the *Getting Started Guide* ([PDF](http://www.config4star.org/download/manuals/config4star-getting-started-guide.pdf), [HTML](http://www.config4star.org/config4star-getting-started-guide/contents.html)) for my [Config4Cpp](http://www.config4star.org/) library.

**Edit**: The Config4Cpp documentation I mentioned might provide inspiration for API design, but I belated realised that you might appreciate advice on implementation options in case you decide to write your own configuration class from scratch (rather than use a third-party library like Config4Cpp) ...

Your class should use a `std::map` to store a collection of *fullyScopedName->value* mappings. Obviously, the *fullyScopedName* will be a string, but there are two options for representing the *value*.

The first option is to represent the *value* as a string. A type-safe accessor such as `getInt()` or `getBool()` will retrieve the string-based value from the map and then parse it to convert it into the desired type. If the parsing fails, then the accessor operation throws an exception. (That is the approach taken by Config4Cpp.)

The second option is to represent *value* as shown in the pseudocode below:

```
enum ValueType { STRING_VAL, INT_VAL, BOOL_VAL };
struct Value {
    ValueType         type;
    union {
        const char *  stringVal;
        int           intVal;
        bool          boolVal;
    } data;
};
```

The implementation of a type-safe accessor can then be coded as follows (pseudocode):

```
int getInt(const char * fullyScopedName)
{
    Value * v = nameValueMap[fullyScopedName];
    if (v->type != INT_VAL) {
        throw WrongTypeException(...);
    }
    return v->data.intVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the class that I'm using now mostly inspired by Nathan's answer except with templated methods:

```
class Settings {
public:
    Settings(void);
    virtual ~Settings(void);

    enum SettingName { General_WindowWidth, General_HomePageUrl,
        General_ShowDownloadsWindow, Privacy_RememberPasswords,
        Privacy_RememberHistory };

    virtual void SetConfigFile(const char * path);
    virtual std::string GetConfigFilePath();
    virtual void Load();
    virtual void Save();

    template<class T>
    T Get(SettingName name) {
        return boost::lexical_cast<T>(settings_[name]);
    }

    template<class T>
    void Set(SettingName name, T value) {
        settings_[name] = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(value);
    }

    void Set(SettingName name, std::string value) {
        settings_[name] = value;
    }

private:
    std::string configFilePath_;
    std::map<SettingName, std::string> settings_;
};
```